# SQL Server - Delete Duplicate Row with conditions

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I´m new with SQL and getting around with it, but I got to a roadblock and could really use some help.

I´m running a query - example below:

```
SELECT
    A.column1, 
    SUM (A.column2) AS column2,
    B.Purchase_Order,
    C.Date_Purchase_Order,
    D.Invoice_Number, D.Date_Payment_Invoice,
    E.column7,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(A.column1) ORDER BY A.column1) AS Count_Duplicates
FROM 
    Table A
LEFT JOIN 
    Table B 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table C 
LEFT JOIN  
    Table D 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table E 
GROUP BY 
    A.column1, A.column2, B.Purchase_Order, C.Date_Purchase_Order, 
    D.Invoice_Number, D.Date_Payment_Invoice, E.column7
```

The output file of `Purchase_Order` and `Date_Purchase_Order` is given by line - so if purchase order has value of $1,000.00 and 10 lines of products it returns 10 lines of purchase at 1,000.00 and the different dates these lines were approved. When I sum up the value of the Purchase Order it returns $10,000 instead of 1,000

What I need to do is based in the row_number count is to identify the most recent date and delete the older ones, having in mind that there are POs with 5 lines, 1 line ( this should not be deleted), 100 lines.

Thanks for all support!

Comment: Traditionally an `on` clause is used with `left join`.  An improper `on` clause would be the cause of duplicates.

Comment: The files I´m joining are extracted in Excel format from my ERP. They already come duplicated from the source. I use SQL to "clean/ upollute" them.

Comment: I got to the point below which is working to count rows:

    SELECT

    *
 
    FROM 

    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PO_Number, 
    PO_Value, Supplier ORDER BY Date_PurchaseOrder) AS 
    Line_Count
,    *

    FROM Table_PO ) AS T

    Where Line_Count = 1 - Is there a way that instead of a WHERE clause I can use a MAX? I couldnt figure out where to put the MAX clause.